# Can't get MapServer WFS to display in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, wfs, mapserver

I'm new to OpenLayers and MapServer and I'm trying to serve a shapefile through a WFS but can't seem to get the data to display. When I use Firebug and HttpFox in Firefox I seem to be getting some data coming back, but it just won't get rendered on my web page. It is entirely possible that I have missed something simple but I can't see what. I've got the following in terms of my setup.

MapFile:

```
MAP

NAME "MapServerWFS"
STATUS on
SIZE 600 600
EXTENT 0 0 700000 1300000
UNITS METERS
SHAPEPATH "shp"
IMAGECOLOR 240 240 240 
PROJECTION
     "init=EPSG:27700"
END

WEB
    TEMPLATE "template.html"
    IMAGEPATH "C:/DevProjects/fgsv2/output/"
    IMAGEURL "../output/"
    METADATA
      "wfs_title"          "WFSDemo" ## REQUIRED
      "wfs_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/DevProjects/fgsv2/mapfile.map&" ## Recommended
      "wfs_srs"            "EPSG:27700" ## Recommended
      "ows_srs"            "EPSG:27700" ## Recommended
      "wfs_abstract"       "This text describes my WFS service. This should be some counties." ## Recommended
      "wfs_enable_request" "*"  # necessary
      "wms_enable_request" "*"  # necessary
      "wms_title"           "WMSDemo"
    END
END

#this connects to a shapefile
LAYER
    NAME "County"
    DATA "County"

    #CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    #CONNECTION "C:/devprojects/fgsv2/shp/County.shp"
    STATUS ON
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:27700"
    END
    METADATA
        "title" "County"
        "wfs_title"         "County" ##REQUIRED
        "wfs_srs"           "EPSG:27700" ## REQUIRED
        "gml_include_items" "all" ## Optional (serves all attributes for layer)
        "gml_featureid"     "db_id" ## REQUIRED
        "wfs_enable_request" "*"
    END

    EXTENT 0 0 700000 1300000
    TYPE POLYGON
    CLASS
        NAME "County"
        STYLE
            color 100 250 250
            outlinecolor 50 50 250
        END
    END 
    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
    dump true
END #end of layer



END # end of map file
```

The data I'm using is English and Welsh Counties, so the projection is set to EPSG:27700. The OpenLayers map and layers bit is as follows:

```
                var farm_style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
            farm_style.strokeWidth = 3;
            farm_style.strokeColor = "#ff0000";
            farm_style.fillOpacity = 0.5;           

            var mymap = new OpenLayers.Map({ div: "map",
                layers: [
                new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("County", {
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ "default": farm_style}), 
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/DevProjects/fgsv2/mapfile.map",
                        version: "1.0.0",
                        featureType: "County",
                        featurePrefix:"ms",
                        featureNS: "http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
                    })
                })
            ,
            ],
                center: [-1, 53],
                zoom: 8
            });
```

When I view the POST and Content through my Firefox addIns I can see
POST:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">
<wfs:Query typeName="ms:County">
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:BBOX>
<ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
<gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
<gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
-2.64794921875,51.35205078125 0.64794921875,54.64794921875
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</ogc:BBOX>
</ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

The reference to EPSG:4326 is abit confusing as I've made no mention of it elsewhere. Is it a default setting somewhere? The Content tab contains the following:

```
    <wfs:FeatureCollection xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs     http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd     http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/DevProjects/fgsv2/mapfile.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAME=ms:County&OUTPUTFORMAT=XMLSCHEMA">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Box srsName="EPSG:27700">
<gml:coordinates>
294170.798523,90299.411200 655604.702242,588517.298279
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
<ms:County fid="County.1">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Box srsName="EPSG:27700">
<gml:coordinates>
320262.500400,378383.398000 361791.001700,422761.904601
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
<ms:msGeometry>
<gml:MultiPolygon srsName="EPSG:27700">
<gml:polygonMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:outerBoundaryIs>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:coordinates>
330996.596900,394516.299901 338224.102200,379434.497000 328536.798900,380475.199200     326182.199000,378383.398000 320262.500400,388522.196000 330996.596900,394516.299901
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:polygonMember>
<gml:polygonMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:outerBoundaryIs>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:coordinates>
330871.099200,405417.000200 335362.999800,402517.699900 337285.798200,405717.803700     344062.801400,398931.696000 348231.000800,404146.903200 351662.604000,402905.498700     361791.001700,394518.799500 355128.200600,395322.399401 354161.500000,387836.602400     350551.103500,389713.904500 344678.600001,382585.295100 334583.800700,388194.599500     326895.800900,406184.799700 336963.201600,422761.904601 330871.099200,405417.000200
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:polygonMember>
</gml:MultiPolygon>
</ms:msGeometry>
<ms:OBJECTID>1    </ms:OBJECTID>
<ms:COUNTY_STR>Merseyside    </ms:COUNTY_STR>
<ms:PMS_REGION>7    </ms:PMS_REGION>
<ms:COUNTRY>ENGLAND    </ms:COUNTRY>
<ms:SNAC_GOR>North West    </ms:SNAC_GOR>
<ms:SHAPE_LEN>2.19563981295e+005    </ms:SHAPE_LEN>
<ms:EARegion>3    </ms:EARegion>
<ms:db_id>1    </ms:db_id>
<ms:updateID>0    </ms:updateID>
<ms:ET_ID>0    </ms:ET_ID>
<ms:ET_X>344814.69641    </ms:ET_X>
<ms:ET_Y>389730.08240    </ms:ET_Y>
<ms:Distance>0.00000000    </ms:Distance>
</ms:County>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<ms:County fid="County.2">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Box srsName="EPSG:27700">
<gml:coordinates>
411883.903568,379684.895552 475119.498243,418312.098600
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
```

These co-ordinates are correct for the data I'm trying to serve so I'm happy that things are appearing to be read ok. Panning and zooming in the map div on my test page will result in the content being altered based on a different bounding box, I just can't see anything. Am I missing some styling information somewhere? I've searched for solutions to this but nothing has worked. There's no proxy set up but my understanding is that for a completely local setup, a proxy is not required.

Please can someone take a look at the setup I have and let me know if I've missed something obvious.

Comment: set the map projection to epsg:27700 - you'll also need to add in the declaration (http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/proj4js/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, where exactly do these lines need to go? My map file projection is set, so do these need to go in the openlayer.protocol bit? Sorry if I'm being dense...

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example#Use_Proj4js_for_other_transformations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @iant for his comments with regards to proj4js, I've now got the mapping sorted. My mapfile uses a "EPSG:27700" for the map and layer projections (as posted originally). Within the calls to OpenLayers I now explicitly set the projection and displayProjection as below:

```
var mymap = new OpenLayers.Map({ div: "map",
                layers: [
                new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("County", {
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700"),
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/DevProjects/fgsv2/mapfile.map",
                        version: "1.0.0",
                        featureType: "County",
                        featurePrefix:"ms",
                        featureNS: "http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
                    })
                })

            ],center: [400000, 300000],zoom:10});
```

The XML Post now references "EPSG:900913" as the SRSName for the box used to query the data. The XML now references "EPSG:27700" when returning the coordinates of the features.